# SSL handshake exception in NetBeans 12.6 IDE for plugin upgrade, Can't install nb-javac plugin

Tags: java, ssl, netbeans, ide

I freshly installed `NetBeans IDE 12.6` with `JDK 11.0`. On first startup it prompts for `nb-javac` plugin to be installed, which is fine. But when I try to install Netbeans can't connect to plugin portals configured. Proxy settings are fine and connection test under proxy settings is successful. Under IDE log  `$HOME/.netbeans/12.6/var/log/messages.log`   it shows a SSL handshake exception with message that remote peer terminated connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that adding a JVM options to use TLSv1.2 resolves this problem. Edit Netbeans configuration file `$NETBEANS_DIR/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf` to add JVM option. Add `-J-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2` at the end for `netbeans_default_options` param, as below

`netbeans_default_options=" <Already present options>  -J-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2"`

Save the file and restart IDE. Try to install plugin again, and it works !!!